# How can I use AutoFixture to create an object but not fill out any properties

Tags: unit-testing, autofixture

Using AutoFixture I can easily create an instance of a data object using the Create method like so:

```
_fixture.Create<FilterItems>()
```

Using this technique I am protected for any changes in the constructor that may come in the future, but it also fills out all properties which in this case (because it's a collection of filters) is not desired.

Is there any way to just tell AutoFixture to create the object, but not fill out any properties?

I know there's a Without method to skip a field, but using that means I have to keep adding to it whereas I'd rather just start with an empty object and add to it if a test needs it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that.

You can do it as a one-off operation:

```
var fi = fixture.Build<FilterItems>().OmitAutoProperties().Create();
```

You can also customize the `fixture` instance to always omit auto-properties for a particular type:

```
fixture.Customize<FilterItems>(c => c.OmitAutoProperties());
```

Or you can completely turn off auto-properties:

```
fixture.OmitAutoProperties = true;
```

If you're using one of the unit testing Glue Libraries like [AutoFixture.Xunit2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2), you can also do it declaratively:

```
[AutoData]
public void MyTest([NoAutoProperties]FilterItems fi)
{
    // Use fi here...
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was just watching your advanced course on Pluralsight. Amazing to get an answer from the author himself in 4 mins no less! Thanks for the answer, I totally misunderstood the AutoProperties documentation which seems to imply (to me) that this feature will skip properties that have a default value and thus not skip values that would otherwise result in a value of default(<type>).

Answer (score 2):

You should call `_fixture.OmitAutoProperties = true;` before creating a specimen.